# Spring: spring-data-mongodb or spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Which's the difference between

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I'm developing an spring boot service.

Answer (score 6):

`spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` contains configuration classes for Spring Boot. It also includes the `spring-data-mongodb` library so you would only need to include the start in your boot app:

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/2.0.5.RELEASE/jar

Answer (score 2):

`spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` is a spring boot starter pom. For more information on starters:
[spring-boot-starters](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starters)

> Dependency management is a critical aspects of any complex project. And doing this manually is less than ideal; the more time you spent on it the less time you have on the other important aspects of the project.
>
> Spring Boot starters were built to address exactly this problem. Starter POMs are a set of convenient dependency descriptors that you can include in your application. You get a one-stop-shop for all the Spring and related technology that you need, without having to hunt through sample code and copy paste loads of dependency descriptors.